# Type sizes, Stind.h, Signed and unsigned integer

Tags: c

For more details, I'm learning from a book (Learn C the hard way) and i have one exercise where he tell me to learn some type sizes but i don't have much details and I don't understand very well what is unsigned and signed integer and where you use it. I have just an idea: unsigned doesn't have negative numbers and signed can have negativ numbers but o the outside world, cannot reach natural numbers as high as unsigned. **Is more then that?**

The book contain some commands **uint_least(N)_t, INT_LEAST(N)_MAX, INT_LEAST(N)_MIN, UINT_LEAST(N)_MAX, int_fast(N)_t, uint_fast(N)_t** but i don't understand what i can do with them.

Tell me please what are they used for? When i use this? are a command like **Int or if?** or you use it in a loop like **i < unit_fast8_t; i++** ?

P.S. My english sucks, i know :( i have difficulty to understand some terms.

Comment: What exact question do you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signed versus UnSigned Integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247873/signed-versus-unsigned-integers)

Comment: When and why do you use unsigned and signed integers?

Comment: @SergiuMan `When and why do you use unsigned and signed integers`..see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336/when-to-use-unsigned-values-over-signed-ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have `int` with only 3 bits available. When you decide you don't
need negative values, you have `2^3 = 8` possible values (including zero) that
can be stored in 3 bit `int`:

```
000 -> 0
001 -> 1
010 -> 2
011 -> 3
100 -> 4
101 -> 5
110 -> 6
111 -> 7
```

This would be **unsigned int** So when you KNOW you don't need negative
values, for example you want to use it to count some loop:

```
for (int_3bit i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Here it's perfectly fine to use unsigned value, because no negative value will
ever be inside the `i` variable. If you add 1 to 7, you will get 0 again, if
you subtract 1 from 0, you will get 7.

But when you *do need a negative values*, you have to use **signed integer**.
Then we have to fit the information about the value's sign *AND* the actual
value into the 3 bits we have available. This can be done in many way, but to
keep it simple, we may use the leftmost bit as a sign indicator. When it's
zero, the number is positive, when it's one, the number is negative. This
leaves only 2 bits for the value, which can now hold only `2^2 = 4` values:

```
000 -> 0

001 -> 1
010 -> 2
011 -> 3

101 -> -1
110 -> -2
111 -> -3
```

This is not very good signed int representation, usually something other is
used
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), but it shows
you some basic differences between signed and unsigned integers:

**Unsigned integers** are good for counting, but not good for arithmetic.

**Signed integers** are good for arithmetic, but when used as counters, they
can count to only a half of the range of unsigned integers (because one bit is
"wasted" to hold a sign).