# C++: warning: Signed and unsigned expression ( Gmake, freebsd )

Tags: c++, expression, unsigned, signed

I'm facing a little problem and I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Here is the error code:

```
FILE.cpp: In member function 'bool DragonSoulTable::ReadAdditionalApplys()':
FILE.cpp:223: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

And here is the code I put on pastebin because it is too big to put that code on forum
[FILE.CPP](http://pastebin.com/3ipXkGDK)

Comment: Just a note about *why* the warning is generated -- imagine the case where  m_vecDragonSoulNames has a *lot* of items in it; e.g. more than 2 billion items (assuming sizeof(size_t)==4 on your computer's architecture).  In that case, the comparison in your for-loop would behave differently depending on whether it compared the two values as signed or unsigned; in the signed case, m_vecDragonSoulNames would likely be re-interpreted as a negative value(!) which means that the for loop would terminate immediately without ever executing the loop body -- probably not the behavior you would expect.

Comment: You might want to check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336/when-to-use-unsigned-values-over-signed-ones/62437270#62437270](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336/when-to-use-unsigned-values-over-signed-ones/62437270#62437270)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to line 223, you have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_vecDragonSoulNames.size(); i++)
```

As you can see, `i` is of type `int` but does `m_vecDragonSoulNames.size()` return an `int`??

In fact, you have a lot of comparisons like this in your code.

Compilers give warnings (not errors) when you compare signed and unsigned types, this is because the ranges of this types are different. And there are good reasons for this, if you dont be careful the results can be surprising...

If you know its safe to make such a comparison, you can explicitly cast one of the values to be of the same type of the other, and the warning will dissapear.

Something like:

```
unsigned int a = someUnisgnedValue;
int b = someSignedValue; 
if ((unsigned) b < a)    
   //... do something
```

Or you can just use both of the same type. For example in the line 223 of your code you can do:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_vecDragonSoulNames.size(); i++)
```

Please, check this other question: [When to use unsigned values over signed ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336/when-to-use-unsigned-values-over-signed-ones)

Comment: Can you give me the correct syntax with which to replace? I am beginner in c ++ I realize its not how to formulate the syntax // 
I just want to disappear that warning.

Comment: @Reby210 See edit, the last choice could be convenient for you. But you should study more about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the warning says. You are comparing signed and unsigned integers. For example:

```
uint NUM = 5;

for (int i=0; i < NUM; i++) // Here you compare int and uint
```

The solution is to

1. make all of your variable the same type,
2. disregard the warning
3. suppress it
4. compile with lower error reporting level and thus not generate it at all.

Answer (score 1):

In that for loop i is integer where as the m_vecDragonSoulNames.size() is of type unsigned integer. make i unsigned int