# Why datastore doesn't support uint?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Reading the datastore documentation[0] I find that it doesn't support unsigned integers (uint, uint8 etc) so I'm wondering what's the technical reason for that. Currently I'm doing a lot of conversions because of this.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities

Comment: Why are you using so many unsigned integers? Do you need that one extra bit of space, or are you doing a lot of bitwise operations?

Comment: This can be important for folks storing crypto-related integers.

Comment: @JimB There are a lot of structures that use unsigned integers. I guess that's why Go supports uint in the first place. I'm wondering why datastore doesn't at least do the conversion to int(and document it) for the shake of convenience.

Comment: @themihai: I don't know precisely why datastore doesn't have unsigned value types. Go doesn't allow implicit type conversions (what happens when the uint value > MaxInt, and some other code compares the result as signed?), so you need to explicitly convert them as needed. My comment was really referring to the fact that you generally don't need or want unsigned values if you have the choice, even if you think they should only be positive. Here's one of many discussions on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336/when-to-use-unsigned-values-over-signed-ones